# Is there an efficient np.sum with exponent operator possible in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, reinforcement-learning

I have a quick question which I can't find asked anywhere (yet). Is there a quick and efficient way to perform an operation like this:

[image: Sum with exponent]

Where gamma is a constant. So to put it simply: take the sum of all gamma's raised to the power of i. I have fooled around a bit with `np.sum` and `np.exp` but this seems to be my best guess:

```
n = 4
gamma = 2
np.sum([gamma**i for i in range(n)])
```

Let me know what you've come up with :)

Comment: I would just do the math for this one: `(gamma ** n - 1)/(gamma - 1)` and leave numpy out of it.

Comment: As @Mark said here you can use a closed form result https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B+a%5Ek%2C+%7Bk%2C0%2Cn-1%7D%5D to get a quicker and more accurate result.

Comment: Ah yes that works perfectly Mark, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mark explained, the best solution is rewriting the sum into the simple formula:

`(gamma ** n - 1)/(gamma - 1)`

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Sorry, you are correct

Answer (score 2):

You can generate all the powers with one `numpy` expression:

```
In [131]: n = 4
     ...: gamma = 2
     ...: np.sum([gamma**i for i in range(n)])
Out[131]: 15
In [132]: np.sum(gamma ** np.arange(n))
Out[132]: 15
```